# Set default outfit as Desmond?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In AC Revelations, I acquired the **Desmond** outfit.

1. Equipped the outfit from the Inventory.
2. Played the game.
3. Waited for it to save.
4. Quit it.
5. Restarted again afterwards.

And my outfit was changed back to the **default**. Is there a way to stop this from happening? It is very irritating to change the outfit whenever I turn the game on.